Do children need a passport to travel by car from the United States to Canada and back?
We are a married couple with 2 children, 7 and 10 years old. All of us are US citizens. Both my spouse and I have US passports. The children currently have no passports or other photo IDs.
What documents do the children need to cross the border by car from the United States into Canada and back?
Related

Minor without passport, transiting through Canada with both US parents - This question says "One of my children has an expired US passport", but this is not the case with us.
Does my 10-month-old child need a passport to cross the USA-Canada border? - This 2014 question is asking about a much younger child.
Does my infant child need a US passport to fly to Canada and back? - This question is about plane (not car) travel, and a much younger child.


Under the age of 16, a state-issued birth certificate (for each child, obviously) is adequate for Canadian and US citizens to cross the land border in either direction, when travelling with both parents in the same vehicle.
As per the comment below, Canada appears to have de-emphasized the minimum acceptable documents for minors. If you believe the US government, this is what they say:

Entry into Canada: Canadian law requires that all persons entering
Canada carry proof of citizenship and identity. A valid U.S. passport,
passport card, or NEXUS card satisfies these requirements for U.S.
citizens.
Children under 16 only need proof of U.S. citizenship.


That source only covers entry to the US. Do you have a source for entry to Canada?

@user102008 Only a US source. As another posting has noted they appear to have de-emphasized the minimum requirements without actually changing them.

One thing I've never understood with using a birth certificate as proof of citizenship when crossing a border: How do you prove that the birth certificate presented belongs to the person trying to cross the border and how does a birth certificate prove current citizenship? Even if a person was born as a US citizen, the citizenship may have been renounced.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well, the same applies to the application of the passport and photo IDs itself; there is no centralized citizenship database in US and Canada, instead the system is built on secondary documents from states (which in turn relying on private documents) and references.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Border officers do conduct investigations if you show up without a photo ID, but in most cases, the child would be travelling with their parents named on the certificate with a photo ID, and the concern is by far about kidnapping rather than illegal entry. Renunciation is an explicit process that governments would have a record of.

Ultimately the political concern for the US-Canada border is very low (despite recent surges in asylum seekers) and the governments deem it unnecessary to strictly enforce it: those who really want to can always use the thousands of miles of unguarded border, though sometimes with tragic results...

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo the adults will have passports or equivalent photo ID and the urchins’ names will be matched and birthdates compared to the humans presented. The concerns with children are mostly abduction (usually by one of the parents). Canadian passports for minors are only valid for 5 years, but even so a photo of an 18-month-old is going to be of little use in identifying a 6–year old child. The birth certificate is evidence of citizenship- as with adult passports, identity is established by other means.

@xngtng Surely, but when applying for a passport, especially the first time, examining the presented proofs of identity will likely take days if not weeks, I presume. It's unlikely something a border control officer can do in minutes or perhaps hours when someone presents themselfes at the border seeking entry.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well, it goes back to my last comment, the political concern is very low even if it is abused, and the constitutional right to enter for citizens is held to a much higher regard.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo And I think you are overestimating the actual checks involved in the system. The passport office don't routinely verify the authenticity of every document from the county/state. And for the most common secondary documents for passport apps, the driver's licence, the verification for its issuance consists of a brief check of original documents by a DMV agent who's likely less trained or experienced than border agents. The system is built on corroboration (e.g. how you can pass TSA with credit cards or library cards), not central databases, and CBP does look for corroborations.

I’m pretty sure they have reciprocal access to auto registration info, which acts as additional corroboration at the land border for most travellers in their own vehicles.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think a minor (under the age of 18) can renounce his US citizenship. I believe the US government will recognize him as a US citizen (assuming he had it to begin with) until the age of 18. Therefore, this query doesn't apply.
